# Reducing Bootstrap's container's lateral margins without creating your custom CSS. Is it possible? How?

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

Here's my web page (I'm sorry, but this post is going to contain quite a few screenshots, I don't see any other way)

[image]

Do you see that scroll bar below the table? I don't like it. So I decided to reduce lateral margins a little bit. Here's a list of what I tried

1. Specify margins manually. Result: no centering

```html
<div class="container m-2">
```

[image]

2. Using `conainer-sm`. Result: no margins at all

```html
<div class="container-sm">
```

[image]

3. Combine both methods. Result: I can't properly describe it, but it's weird

```html
<div class="container-sm m-2">
```

[image]

4. Using `mx`. Result: no centering

```html
<div class = "container mx-4">
```

[image]

I [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bootstrap%20container%20margin) on StackOverflow too (and [googled](https://www.google.ru/search?q=bootstrap%20reduce%20container%20margin&oq=reduce%20bootstrap%20con&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

**How do I reduce lateral margins of my container without overriding Bootstrap's CSS with my custom stylesheet?**

It seems over the top to create your CSS for such a trivial thing (even if it's as little as `<style> .container {margin-left: 4 rem; margin-right: 4 rem} </style>`)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<!-- and so forth -->
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPD:** My latest findings

It has something to do with `container`'s `max-width` (if I increase it from 1140 to, say, 2000, the margins shrink) and also with the outer-most `row`. See this dashed area? It's what de-facto increases the margin on the right

[image]

I guess `mw-100` and `justify-content-center` are my friends in this situation? It appears so

Comment: Please update with the actual HTML code and CSS in play here not just pictures of code

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss What code should I include besides those `<div>`s?

Comment: I created a snippet to get you started; put the parts that reproduce the issue in there.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I don't have an _issue_ per say. I just want to know the way to reduce lateral margins, that's it

Comment: Your "issue" is you don't want a scroll bar; so paste the smallest amount of HTML in the snippet that reproduces/shows that

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss It's just a little bit of context, a backstory. It's not an _issue_, surely. A rule of thumb with my questions here is that you should (if you want to) answer the line in bold

Comment: My point is give us some actual rendered HTML that illustrates the issue NOT JUST A PICTURE of it so we can best assist you..  Reference: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors  Note how many of your questions have gone unansered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reduce the sizing of Bootstrap containers without overriding the breakpoints that control them, or without overriding the specific container class CSS.

However, you can switch to the fluid container and contain *that* with a custom container having widths of your choosing.

Also, `container-sm` isn't a valid Bootstrap 4 class.

```css
.container,
.container-fluid {
  background: pink;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.container-container {
  max-width: 95vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .container-container {
    max-width: 90vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .container-container {
    max-width: 85vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Standard container column content here.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">Custom container container column content here.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in container-fluid class instead of container to make the container span the full width of the viewport. This can help eliminate any unwanted lateral margins.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Your content here -->
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to _eliminate_ margins, I want to _reduce_ them (while maintaining centering)